# How to prove that this kernel has codimension 1?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi\in X'$ , where X is a Hilbert space and $X'$ its dual. Then I want to check that $\ker\phi$ is a closed subspace of $X$ of codimension 1 ($\phi \ne 0$).

So to see the closeness we pick a sequence $(x_n) \in \ker \phi$ that converges to $x$, then, since $\phi$ is a bounded functional it is continuous, thus $\phi((x_n)) \to \phi(x)=0$ therefore $\ker \phi$ is closed.

The thing is that I don't know how to attached the socond part, because I think I need to prove that the space $X/ \ker \phi=\{x+\ker \phi : x \in X\}$ has dimension 1.

Can someone help me to prove this assertion please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Note that the image of $\phi$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (or whatever field your Hilbert space is over).

Comment: Can you elaborate more in this please? Thanks :)

Comment: The dual space consists of all bounded linear functionals, which are linear maps from a normed (Banach, Hilbert, etc.) space $X$ into the field $\mathbb K$, which is usually $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Thus the image of $\phi$ is isomorphic (as a vector space) to $\mathbb K$.

Comment: Rigth :), but how does that shows that the kernel has codimension 1?

Comment: Don't forget you need $\phi \ne 0$...

Comment: Right, sorry I forgot to mention that ;)

Comment: I should say $X/K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb K$, where $K$ is the kernel of $\phi$. (Usually called the homomorphism theorem.)

Comment: Why is that?, I undertsand that the $Im \phi $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$ as you pointed out but I don't understand the above comment

Comment: I apologise, I mean to say that the image of $\phi$ *is* $\mathbb K$, and that $X/K$ is isomorphic (as a vector space) to $\mathbb K$. Note that $\mathbb K$ has dimension 1.

Comment: I don't understand the isomorphism.Can you clarify please? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $z\not\in \ker\phi$, the observe that for each $x\in X$, 
$$x= \frac{\phi(x)}{\phi(z)} z - \frac{\phi(x)}{\phi(z)} z + x\\
= \frac{\phi(x)}{\phi(z)} z + \bigg[x - \frac{\phi(x)}{\phi(z)} z \bigg]$$
and $\bigg[x - \frac{\phi(x)}{\phi(z)} z \bigg] \in ker \phi$. This means that $X$ can be written as the direct sum of its two subspaces that is 
$$X = \text{span} \{z \}\oplus \ker \phi.$$
Therefore the $\ker \phi$ has codim $1$.

Comment: Thank you , let me check it , if I have further questions , can I let you know ?

Comment: @user162343 Sure! Glad to help.

Comment: @Xiao Correct me if I'm wrong, but this proof works for any linear functional $\phi$ on a vector space $X$, right?

Comment: @zxmkn Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 10):

This is a purely algebraic result that you can prove without using the inner product or any other additional structure on your vector space:

> **Proposition.** Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $\phi\colon V\to\mathbb{F}$ be a nontrivial linear functional. Then $\ker(\phi)$ has codimension 1.

The proof will consist of the following three steps:

1. Note that, by the first isomorphism theorem, $V/\ker(\phi)\cong\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ (as $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces).
2. Note that $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}$, and that the only subspaces of $\mathbb{F}$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ itself. Since $\phi$ is nontrivial, the only possibility is $\operatorname{im}(\phi)=\mathbb{F}$.
3. Use the fact that isomorphic spaces have the same dimension to conclude that $\operatorname{codim}_\mathbb{F}(\ker(\phi))\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\dim_\mathbb{F}(V/\ker(\phi))=\dim_\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{F})=1$.